# How can i call an ajax function twice (onchange)

Tags: php, ajax, function

This is my ajax funcion

```
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    XMLHttpRequestObject= new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    XMLHttpRequestObject= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function getData(dataSource, divID)
{
    document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = "Loading...";
    if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
    {
        var obj=document.getElementById(divID);
        //alert(dataSource);
        var dataSource = dataSource+'&done=ok';
        XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);
        XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange =function ()
        {
            if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200){
                obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
                document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            } //else {alert ('error'+dataSource)}
        }

        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);

    }
}
```

and this is another function call above ajax function twice:

```
function getCityResult(value){
    getData('aids/getRoutAjax.php?city='+value , 'rout');
    getData('aids/getOriginDestAjax.php?city='+value , 'OriginDest');
}
```

and i have select menu as following:

```
<select name="city_id" id="city_id" class="" style="width:300px;" onchange="return getCityResult(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="13">ABQ</option>
    <option value="12">MUB</option>
    <option value="14">UDH</option>
</select>

<div id="rout"> 
    //Show some data
</div>
<div id="OriginDest">
    // Show some data
</div>
```

my result is calling first one only to show data on div with id [rout]
How can i call both on same time by this way??

Thanks

Comment: did you consider making use of a library like jquery or dojo to do this?your code will look a lot more cleaner and shorter when you use a library to perform ajax calls.

Comment: Not really sure I understand your question ... you are calling both at the same time .... why dont you just return all of the data in 1 call to a single PHP function

Comment: Your code looks OK. Open up a browser debugger and look at the NET tab. See if the second AJAX call is firing at all.

Comment: may be better to call sencond AJAX on success of the first? or you need do that synchronously? Or do it in one ajax request.

Comment: You need to make them synchronous

Comment: @AntonSementsov ... No problem but give me the code please :)

Comment: use jquery ajax it will be more simple and easy.. it took several minutes to understand how to use it http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Both of them should be called, there's no reason it only works for the first one if your code is correct in getOriginDestAjax.php .
To be sure of it, try by calling both on the same page :

```
getData('aids/getRoutAjax.php?city='+value , 'rout');
getData('aids/getRoutAjax.php?city='+value , 'OriginDest');
```